# Why doesnt change value in auth.guard?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, guard

I have a variable `loggined`, the value of which I change using the `logTog()` method. In this method, I make a request to the service where I transfer the current result `to auth.guard`. In the console "undefined" why and how to fix?

**code of AppComponent:**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    loggined: boolean = false;

    constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService) {}
    
    ngOnInit() {
        this.logTog();
    }
    
    logTog(): void {
        this.loggined = !this.loggined;
        this.galleryService.auth(this.loggined);
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```js
    auth(log:boolean):boolean {
        console.log(log);
        return log;
    }
```

**guard:**

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, OnInit {
  constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.galleryService.auth();
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Not related but you are probably looking for `logged_in`. You also don't need to set a type when assigning a value in the declaration.

Comment: In the **guard** file the canActivate function should return true or false. You are returning this.galleryService.auth()  from canActivate but you are not passing any argument to the function.

Comment: @nilansh How to pass corectly  the value of the variable "this.loggined" in "guard"?

Comment: @IgorShvets You can see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a service to access the value of this.loggedIn in AppComponent as well as AuthGuard. Instead of declaring this.loggedIn variable in AppComponent declare it in the service.

**LoggedInService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoggedInService {

  constructor(
    private router:Router
  ) { }

  private loggedIn;

  setLoggedIn(data){
   // Change Value of this.loggedIn to true or false according to your logic 
  }

  getLoggedIn(){
   return this.loggedIn;
  }

}
```

**App.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService,
            private loggedInService: LoggedInService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.logTog();
  }

  logTog(): void {
    this.loggedInService.loggedIn = !this.loggedInService.loggedIn;
    this.galleryService.auth(this.loggedInService.loggedIn);
  }
}
```

**auth file remains same according to your logic**

//Same code

**guard.ts**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, OnInit {
  constructor(private galleryService: GalleryService,
              private loggedInService: LoggedInService
  ) {}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.galleryService.auth(this.loggedInService.loggedIn);
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```